# jQuery response saved as PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a php page which generates links based on results from an "USERS" table, "NAME" row.
I'm using a jQuery tooltip so that a div appears when those links are hovered.
When the hover happens, I am able to get the link's text using `$(this).text()`, however, I don't seem to be able to parse the result so that it can link with PHP, as I want to display in the 'hidden' div certain info about the HOVERED user (e.g. his e-mail address).

Something like: When "Mike" is hovered, show Mike's e-mail address in the hover div.. and so on.

I've tried with cookies (when mouseover happens, I used something like:

```
$.post("gophp.php", {"name":$(this).text()}, function(results) {
    nada
});
```

, with gophp.php setting a cookie with data from `$_POST['name']`) - the div inside the other page is then able to show the cookie, BUT if I hover some other link, the data which is displayed remains the same because the page has to be reloaded.

Please help me, I'm going nuts.

Comment: Please show a condensed version of your markup, including the element that you hover and the element that is supposed to contain the output.

Comment: the element that I hover is a normal link, the element that is supposed to contain the output is a normal div, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you trying to use cookies?
Why dont you use:

```
$.post("gophp.php", {"name":$(this).text()}, function(results) {
  $('div').html(results);
});
```

and in your `gophp.php`:

```
<?php echo 'some_mail@address.com' ?>
```

(You have to adapt both php and jquery to your situation)

Comment: and include in the gophp.php code for getting the $_POST['name']'s e-mail address for the DB?

Comment: of course you have to change the `gophp.php` file. I was just showing an example

Answer (score 0):

This seems a horrible way around what you're wanting to do. Just have the email address on the page, but initially hidden, and show it on hover.

For example, in your HTML have:

```
<ul class="people-list">
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <span class="name">Martin Bean</span>
      <span class="email">martin@example.com</span>
    </a>
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then to style it:

```
.people-list a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.people-list .name, .people-list .email {
    display: block;
}
.people-list a .email {
    display: none;
}
.people-list a:hover .email {
    display: block;
}
```

Should do the trick in a primitive fashion. You can then position/style as necessary.

Of course, why you want email addresses public available is a whole different topic of conversation.

Comment: You're saying it's a horrible way of doing it because you haven't understood what I'm trying to do... the e-mail address will be requested by PHP from a sql database, should I create a hidden div with all the people found in the 'name' row and all the info about them (maybe I want to display more info than the e-mail, what then?)? For me, that's a horrible way of doing it. I just can't load all info for all users, that's so primitive, I just want to load specific info on a certain hovered user.

Comment: As for your 'why' question, it involves a list of links with people available to help on certain topics, when hovered - it will be displayed their name, e-mail address and other info as well.

Thank you for your time&reply, I'm really grateful!